# raise ValueError if None as value in dict __setitem__

Tags: python, dictionary, collections

Is it possible to raise a ValueError if a new value in dict is a None? Is it possible without creating a new class based on `dict` and overloading `__setitem__` or checking each value before setting?

```py
d = dict()
d["va1"] = None  # should to raise ValueError
```

Is there any out of the box *no Nones dict*?

Comment: What *specific* reason(s) do you have for not creating a subclass?

Comment: I want to use it in only 1 place it the project and I hoped is there something smarter such as `defaultdict(not None)`.

Comment: Why did you hope that? Are you playing code golf? A subclass would only require five simple lines of code. It's just not worth worrying about unless there's a genuine *programming reason* for not using a custon type.

Comment: just learning
Now I'm sure I checked the docs well, because there is no other option.

Answer (score 0):

```
def set_value(dictionary, key, value):
    if value is None:
        raise ValueError("None as values is not allowed")
    dictionary[key] = value


d = dict()
set_value(d, "val1", None)
```

You can do this using the function, and this is the easiest way out.

And if you are deadest on overloading `__setitem__` you can use

> pyrsistent

example :

```
from pyrsistent import pmap

def non_rej_dict():
    def setitem(self, key, value):
        if value is None:
            raise ValueError("None as values is not allowed")
        return super(type(self), self).set(key, value)

    return pmap().evolver().extend({ '__setitem__': setitem }).persistent()


d = non_rej_dict()
d["val1"] = None
```